# MONO (ARM) running webserver using OWIN

Tags: mono, arm, owin

I built mono for armv5 I can run a simple helloworld.exe but when I try to
run webserver which uses owin I am having some problems. I believe I need
the library libmono-system-core4.0-cil but I can't seem to find it anywhere
for arm.

mono-4.2.2.30 was built using

> ./configure --with-tls=__thread --without-mcs-docs
>   CFLAGS=-DARM_FPU_NONE
>   --disable-mcs-build --host=arm-v5te-linux-gnueabi

Here is the error output

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies.
>   IO.FileName_Name   at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Services.ServiceProvider.Add (System.Type
>   serviceType, System.Type implementationType) <0xb6f608e8 + 0x00047> in
>   :0   at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Services.ServicesFactory+<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0
>   (System.Type service, System.Type implementation) <0xb6f608a0 +
>   0x00033> in :0   at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Services.ServicesFactory+<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3
>   (System.Type service, System.Type implementation) <0xb6f60200 +
>   0x0014b> in :0   at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Services.ServicesFactory.DoCallback
>   (System.Action`2 callback) <0xb6f5ffd8 + 0x00037> in <filename
>   unknown>:0   at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Services.ServicesFactory.DoCallback
>   (IDictionary`2 settings, System.Action`2 callback) <0xb6f5f930 +
>   0x000df> in <filename unknown>:0   at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Services.ServicesFactory.Create (IDictionary`2
>   settings, System.Action`1 configuration) <0xb6f5cff8 + 0x00103> in
>   <filename unknown>:0   at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Services.ServicesFactory.Create (IDictionary`2
>   settings) <0xb6f5cfa8 + 0x00023> in :0   at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.BuildServices
>   (Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.StartOptions options) <0xb6f5ce48 + 0x00037>
>   in :0   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start
>   (Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.StartOptions options) <0xb6f5cd90 + 0x0001b>
>   in :0   at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start[TStartup]
>   (Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.StartOptions options) <0xb6f5c908 + 0x00047>
>   in :0   at PLT.Web.Program.main (System.String[]
>   argv) <0xb6f580d0 + 0x0010b> in :0 [ERROR] FATAL
>   UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies.
>   IO.FileName_Name   at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Services.ServiceProvider.Add (System.Type
>   serviceType, System.Type implementationType) <0xb6f608e8 + 0x00047> in
>   :0   at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Services.ServicesFactory+<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0
>   (System.Type service, System.Type implementation) <0xb6f608a0 +
>   0x00033> in :0   at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Services.ServicesFactory+<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3
>   (System.Type service, System.Type implementation) <0xb6f60200 +
>   0x0014b> in :0   at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Services.ServicesFactory.DoCallback
>   (System.Action`2 callback) <0xb6f5ffd8 + 0x00037> in <filename
>   unknown>:0   at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Services.ServicesFactory.DoCallback
>   (IDictionary`2 settings, System.Action`2 callback) <0xb6f5f930 +
>   0x000df> in <filename unknown>:0   at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Services.ServicesFactory.Create (IDictionary`2
>   settings, System.Action`1 configuration) <0xb6f5cff8 + 0x00103> in
>   <filename unknown>:0   at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Services.ServicesFactory.Create (IDictionary`2
>   settings) <0xb6f5cfa8 + 0x00023> in :0   at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.BuildServices
>   (Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.StartOptions options) <0xb6f5ce48 + 0x00037>
>   in :0   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start
>   (Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.StartOptions options) <0xb6f5cd90 + 0x0001b>
>   in :0   at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start[TStartup]
>   (Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.StartOptions options) <0xb6f5c908 + 0x00047>
>   in :0   at PLT.Web.Program.main (System.String[]
>   argv) <0xb6f580d0 + 0x0010b> in :0